# Populate Ordinal column sequentially

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to populate ordinal column but don't want to loop through records. Is there any way to do it in single update?

```
CREATE TABLE #Sample
(PrimaryKey Int NOT NULL,
ParentKey Int NOT NULL,
Ordinal Int NULL)

INSERT #Sample (PrimaryKey, ParentKey, Ordinal) VALUES (1, 1, NULL)
INSERT #Sample (PrimaryKey, ParentKey, Ordinal) VALUES (2, 1, NULL)
INSERT #Sample (PrimaryKey, ParentKey, Ordinal) VALUES (3, 1, NULL)
INSERT #Sample (PrimaryKey, ParentKey, Ordinal) VALUES (4, 2, NULL)
INSERT #Sample (PrimaryKey, ParentKey, Ordinal) VALUES (5, 2, NULL)
INSERT #Sample (PrimaryKey, ParentKey, Ordinal) VALUES (6, 3, NULL)
INSERT #Sample (PrimaryKey, ParentKey, Ordinal) VALUES (7, 4, NULL)
INSERT #Sample (PrimaryKey, ParentKey, Ordinal) VALUES (8, 4, NULL)
INSERT #Sample (PrimaryKey, ParentKey, Ordinal) VALUES (9, 5, NULL)

SELECT * FROM #Sample
DROP TABLE #Sample
```

Values in Ordinal column would be 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1
I want to number within each group. Group defined by "ParentKey" and Ordinal should go sorted by "PrimaryKey"

Important! Can't rely on values in PrimaryKey and ParentKey. They have "holes" and not necessary increment by 1 as shown in my sample..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming SQL Server 2005+:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ParentKey ORDER BY PrimaryKey )
    FROM #Sample
)
UPDATE CTE
SET Ordinal = RN
```